# ERROR pipeline/output.go:100 Failed to connect to backoff(async(tcp://logstash:5044)) - ELK Filebeat .NET Core 3.1 Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, asp.net-core, docker-compose, filebeat

I'm having a strange problem I can't work out as my problem, when searching for this error, is different.  People seem to have experienced this when trying to connect `Filebeat` to `Logstash`.

However, I am trying to write logs directly to `Elasticsearch` but I am getting `Logstash` related errors even though I am not even spinning up a container in `Docker Compose`??

Main Docker Compose File:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  filebeat:
    container_name: filebeat
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: filebeat.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/var/log
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.2
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - cluster.name=docker-
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - esnet
  elastichq:
    container_name: elastichq
    image: elastichq/elasticsearch-hq
    ports:
      - 8080:5000
    environment:
      - HQ_DEFAULT_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - HQ_ENABLE_SSL=False
      - HQ_DEBUG=FALSE
    networks:
      - esnet  
networks:
  esnet:
```

`DockerFile` for `Filebeat`

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.5.2
COPY filebeat/filebeat.yml /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
USER root
RUN chown root:filebeat /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
RUN chmod 644 /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
USER filebeat
```

I am trying to read `json` logs that are already in `Elasticsearch` format, so after reading the docs I decided to try and write directly to `Elasticsearch` which seems to be valid depending on the application.

My `Sample.json` file:

> {"@timestamp":"2020-02-10T09:35:20.7793960+00:00","level":"Information","messageTemplate":"The value of i is {LoopCountValue}","message":"The value of i is 0","fields":{"LoopCountValue":0,"SourceContext":"WebAppLogger.Startup","Environment":"Development","ApplicationName":"ELK Logging Demo"}}

My `Filebeat.yml`:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.json
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true
  json.message_key: log  

#----------------------------- Elasticsearch output --------------------------------

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
  index: "sample-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
```

As stated in the title of this post, I get this message in the console:

> filebeat         | 2020-02-10T09:38:24.438Z     ERROR   pipeline/output.go:100  Failed to connect to backoff(async(tcp://logstash:5044)): lookup logstash on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host

Then when I eventually try and visualize the data in `ElasticHq`, inevitably, nothing is there.

So far, I've tried using commands like `docker prune` just in case theres something funny going on with Docker.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure that filebeat reads your `Filebeat.yml` file?

Comment: I've just updated my post, yes is the answer, as its getting copied into the Filebeat container via a custom `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 1):

You have misconfigured your filebeat.yml file. Look at this error:

```
Failed to connect to backoff(async(tcp://logstash:5044))
```

Filebeat tries to connect to logstash, beacause this is the default configuration. In fact on one hand you show a filebeat.yml file and on the other hand, you haven't mounted it on /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml - look at your volumes settings

```
  filebeat:
    container_name: filebeat
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: filebeat.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/var/log
    networks:
      - esnet
```

You should mount it. If you try to copy it inside a docker container with dockerfile - why?????is necessary reinvent the wheel and add complexity? - you should use the root user:

```
USER root
```

and add root user to your service in docker-compose.yml:

```
user: root
```

Comment: I've added `./filebeat/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml` to my `volume` and kept the Filebeat `Dockerfile` the same (see in my post `filebeat.Dockerfile`).  Where does `user: root` go in the `docker-compose`?  Within Filebeat, or somewhere else?

Comment: yep, at the same level of networks or volumes, or container_name

Comment: Thanks, I've just put it under `container_name` and I get: `Exiting: error loading config file: config file ("filebeat.yml") can only be writable by the owner but the permissions are "-rw-rw-r--" (to fix the permissions use: 'chmod go-w /usr/share/`

Comment: run the command suggested chmod go-w /path/to/your/filebeat.yml on your desktop, then rerun docker-compose

Comment: I have a new error now: `2020-02-10T12:05:41.619Z     ERROR   pipeline/output.go:100  Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://elasticsearch:9200)): Get http://elasticsearch:9200`

Comment: this is strange.. elastic is up? please post output of docker ps

Comment: Yeah, I've googled it and found no solution, I even made sure Elasticsearch was spun up first in `docker-compose`.  Just done `docker ps` and its running on port `9200`.  I also tried `localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v` via the browser and it works.  `docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.2   "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp   elasticsearch`

Comment: there is something interesting in the elasticsearch logs?

Comment: I've just tried putting the logs in my post but there is too much text and I've crashed the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207528/discussion-between-user1574598-and-lupanoide).